# Haw create .alx file for several device?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

There are several versions of my applications for devices with different resolutions (9800, 9650, 9330). How can I create for him a single file. Alx? Are there other ways to merge versions of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article [Create a single .alx file to install multiple versions of an application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Create-a-single-alx-file-to-install-multiple-versions-of-an/ta-p/445156)

In this article there is a statement that you may use additional attributes defined in Device.xml file, which is located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Research In Motion\AppLoader.

For your case there are two attributes **model** and **series**

Use these attributes to specify the particular device model for the application to be installed.